# How to print just more than one match python regex

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I have this code, that searches for matches, using regex.

```
with open('ip-new.txt','r') as csvfile1, open('city.txt', 'r', encoding="utf8" ) as file1:
    readCS = csv.reader(csvfile1, delimiter=';')
    reader = file1.readlines()
    for row in readCS:
        for line in reader:
            if all(re.search(fr"\b{word}\b", line, re.IGNORECASE) for word in row[:2]):
                print(str(row) + line)
```

Once i run this i will get the matches i am looking for, but obviously there may be more than one match, so i get the following output:

```
['ZA', 'EAST LONDON'] 'id': 'ZA~EC~East London'

['GB', 'BRIDGWATER'] 'id': 'GB~ENG~Bridgwater'

['GH', 'TEMA'] 'id': 'GH~AA~Tema'

['TH', 'BANGKOK'] 'id': 'TH~10~Bangkok'

['TH', 'BANGKOK'] 'id': 'TH~10~Bangkok Noi'

['TH', 'BANGKOK'] 'id': 'TH~10~Bangkok Yai'
```

The first 3 matches are uniq, so i dont have the need to print them, I am looking just to print anything that  as more than one match.
I am not sure how i can fit in a counter a do this with a while loop. as i tried and was unsuccessful . I may be doing something wrong, not a programmer by any means. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just store the lines in a list and print them if you get more than one:

```
for row in readCS:
    lines = [line for line in reader
        if all(re.search(fr"\b{word}\b", line, re.IGNORECASE) for word in row[:2])]
    if len(lines) > 1:
        for line in lines:
            print(str(row) + line)
```

Comment: thank you very much! exactly what i was looking for !